# React Navigation - navigate from TabNavigator to StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate from one of the tabs in TabNavigator to a screen in the StackNavigator with a reset action. Here is (abbreviated) code:

```
...

const FriendsNavigator = StackNavigator({
 Friends: { screen: Friends },
})

const TabsNavigator = TabNavigator({
 Home: { screen: HomeNavigator },
 Schedule: { screen: ScheduleNavigator },
 Friends: { screen: FriendsNavigator },
 Activity: { screen: ActivityNavigator }
})

const Main = StackNavigator({
 Login: { screen: Login },
 Tabs: { screen: TabsNavigator }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Main', () => Main);
```

I'm trying to get from `Friends` in `FriendsNavigator` to `Login` in `Main` and reset the stack (as if the user was logging out). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: from any tab component : this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");

Comment: No this is not working. I have the same Issue. When i tried to debug i don't see any errors in the Debug console. How ever nothing happens after calling navigate !!

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new to all this, but I think you need to have a master (my word) navigator.  I make mine a stackNavigator, and then hide it when I don't want it - likewise with the tabNavigator.

Here is my code that works:

```
 const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
      loginForm: { screen: LoginForm },
      main: {
        screen: TabNavigator({
          groupMain: { screen: GroupMain },
          feedback: { screen: Feedback },
          settings: { screen: Settings },
          groupScreen: {
            screen: TabNavigator({
            groupScreens:  { screen: GroupPage},
            feedbackInput: { screen: FeedbackInput}
            })
          }
        })
      }
    }, {
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarVisible: false,
        header: null
      }
    });
```